# NOTY queue and append functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, noty

I am using Noty for error notification.

Scenario : When page loads there can be lots of error icons(generated at run time).

what i want is :  that on click of each icon the error message appends but if i again click on the same error message then error message should not gets append.

Can anyone please tell me what needs to be done in this case using noty?